# How can i specify the working directory for jupyter notebooks from the command line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a python project with jupyter notebooks and would like to save them in their own sub directory (e.g. `jupyter_notebooks`). Now I want to start jupyter, so that the notebooks will use the project root as cwd and not the directory they are in. Something like this:

```
python -m jupyter --cwd=project\root
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `--notebook-dir` argument:

```
python -m jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/path/to/directory
```

Or simply just:

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/path/to/directory
```

You can see all options for the command by running `jupyter notebook --help`.

If you want the notebook server to always use a specific directory without supplying the argument, you can generate a configuration file for the notebook server by running:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

The name of the created file will be printed to the console. Then, in this file, **uncomment** and edit the line where you find the variable `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir`, e.g.:

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/path/to/directory'
```

Comment: This is not entirely what I want. Because if I do this and open a notebook, the cwd will be the direcotry given with the "notebook-dir" parameter. But I can use this as a workaround.